# Changing Existing Project causes Unsafe Control Error

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have a control that Works. I am trying to go through and rename the project namespaces, etc so that I can reuse the part. However, when I'm debugging and i try to add the control, I get an "WebPart Could Not be Found Or Not Registered as Safe" error. What am I doing wrong when changing the files? I'm using the same name throughout.